# RxSwift - Use two observable to make a async call

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

Lets say I have a function that takes in two arguments - `Observable<String?>` and `Observable<Person?`> and returns Observable

This is my sample code below:

```
return  Observable.combineLatest(self.id, personStream)
                  map { [weak self] (id,person) -> Person? in

     guard let person = person as? Person else {
       return nil
     }

    if let id = id {
       // How do I return this updated person
       self?.updatePersonDetails(for: person, completion: { (updatedPerson) in
            return updatedPerson
       })     
    } else {
       return person
    }
}
```

How do I return this updated person inside this mapping function?

Update:

```
public func updatePerson(personStream: Observable<Person>) -> Observable<Person> {
    return Observable.combineLatest(
            self.id,
            personStream
        ).flatMap { [weak self] (id,person) -> Observable<Person?> in

            guard let person = person as? Double else {
                return Observable.just(nil)
            }

            if let id = id {
                // How do I return this updated person
                return Observable.create { [weak self] observer in
                    self?.updatePersonDetails(for: person, completion: { (updatedPerson) in
                        observer.on(.next(updatedPerson))
                        observer.on(.completed)
                    })
                    return Disposables.create()
                }
            } else {
                return Observable.just(person)
            }
        }
}
```

The above function is called as below:

```
let personUpdateStream = personService.updatePerson(personStream: personDataStream)
Observable.combineLatest(personUpdateStream, nameStream,profileEnabledStream)
.subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] (person, name, isEnabled) in
                print(name)
                self?.updatePersonView(person: person, name: name, isLocked: !isEnabled)
            })
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Issue: The block inside combineLatest with the `print(name)` never runs. May I know whats the issue here?

Description of `personUpdateStream`

`personUpdateStream   RxSwift.FlatMap<(String?, Person?), RxSwift.Observable<Person?>>    0x0000604001e5af70`

Comment: Are you sure `personUpdateStream`, `nameStream` and `profileEnabledStream` each emitted at least one value? `combineLatest` requires each stream inside to emit at least once before it can start emitting itself.

Comment: try attaching `debug()` to each inbound stream

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `flatMap` instead of `map` and to integrate your non Rx call of `updatePersonDetails` you should use `Observable.create`.

Your final code should look something similar to:

```
return Observable.combineLatest(
            self.id,
            personStream
        ).flatMap { [weak self] (id,person) -> Observable<Person?> in

            guard let person = person as? Double else {
                return Observable.just(nil)
            }

            if let id = id {
                // How do I return this updated person
                return Observable.create { [weak self] observer in
                    self?.updatePersonDetails(for: person, completion: { (updatedPerson) in
                        observer.on(.next(updatedPerson))
                        observer.on(.completed)
                    })
                    return Disposables.create()
                }
            } else {
                return Observable.just(person)
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please remove my changes. I have updated the question

Comment: @DesperateLearner please see my suggestion in the OP comments. Another issue could be that you use `weak self` and don't retain your object anywhere. If it's deallocated `self?.updatePersonDetails` will not be called.